# $\inf_{a\in\mathbb{C}}\|f-a\|_{L^{\infty}(I)}\le|I|\|f'\|_{L^{\infty}(I)}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, inequality

Let $I\subset\mathbb{R}$ be an interval of finite length and $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ a function that is differentiable on a neighborhood of $I$. I tried to prove:$$
\inf_{a\in\mathbb{C}}\|f-a\|_{L^{\infty}(I)}\le|I|\|f'\|_{L^{\infty}(I)}
$$
If the range of $f$ and $a$ are both in $\mathbb{R}$, then I can prove this inequality. The key observation is that at minimum, $f-a$ must equal to 0 at some point in $I$ and so I can write this function as an integral over a subset of $I$ by *fundamental theorem of calculus*. But when it comes to $\mathbb{C}$, I don't have a very clear geometric picture as in the $\mathbb{R}$ case. I tried to Work on real and complex parts of $f$ separately, but I can't get back $|f'|$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because $f$ is differentiable on a neighborhood of $I$ we can assume that $I = [c,d] $ with $c < d$. Setting $b = f(c)$ we get for every $x \in I$
\begin{align*}
 |f(x) - b|
 &= \left| \int_{c}^x f'(t) \,\text{d}t \right|
 \leq \int_{c}^x |f'(t)| \,\text{d}t
 \leq \int_{c}^x \|f'\|_{L^\infty(I)} \,\text{d}t \\
 &= \|f'\|_{L^\infty(I)} (x-c)
 \leq |I| \|f'\|_{L^\infty(I)}.
\end{align*}
(Here we estimate the distance of $f(c)=b$ and $f(x)$ by the length of the curve described by $f$). Therefore
$$
 \|f-b\|_{L^\infty(I)}
 = \sup_{x \in I} |f(x)-b|
 \leq |I| \|f'\|_{L^\infty(I)}
$$
and thus
$$
 \inf_{a \in \mathbb{C}} \|f-a\|_{L^\infty(I)}
 \leq \|f-b\|_{L^\infty(I)}
 \leq |I| \|f'\|_{L^\infty(I)}.
$$

Comment: I see. So in fact we don't need the geometric pic. It is just fundamental theorem.

Comment: I wouldn’t say that we don’t use a geometric intuition: We think of $f|_I \colon I \to \mathbb{C}$ as describing a curve in the (complex) plane. The right hand side $|I| \|f'\|_{L^\infty(I)}$ is the length of that curve. For a point $a \in \mathbb{C}$ the term $\|f-a\|_{L^\infty(I)}$ expresses how far away a point in this curve can be from $a$. A natural idea to get desired estimate for some point $b \in \mathbb{C}$ is to let $b$ be the starting point of the curve: Clearly the curve cannot move away farther from its starting points then its length.

Comment: Good point. $|I|\|f'\|_{L^{\infty}(I)}$ is an upper bound for the length of the curve.